# Laravel 5.6. How to test JSON/JSONb columns

Tags: laravel, postgresql, jsonb, laravel-5.6, laravel-testing

`$this->assertDatabaseHas()` not working with `JSON`/`JSONb` columns.

So how can I tests these types of columns in Laravel?

Currently, I have a store action. How can I perform an assertion, that a specific column with pre-defined values was saved.

Something like

`['options->language', 'en']`

is **NOT** an option, cause I have an extensive JSON with meta stuff.

How can I check the `JSON` in DB at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPD

Now can be done [like that](https://laravel-news.com/testing-json-columns?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Unit%20Testing%20JSON%20Columns%20in%20Laravel%20Laravel%20Forge%20now%20has%20support%20for%20Laravel%20Octane%20Handling%20Signals%20in%20Console%20Commands%20and%20more%20-%20356&utm_content=Unit%20Testing%20JSON%20Columns%20in%20Laravel%20Laravel%20Forge%20now%20has%20support%20for%20Laravel%20Octane%20Handling%20Signals%20in%20Console%20Commands%20and%20more%20-%20356%20CID_2c439bea767e0e15a48f9714321d6721&utm_source=email%20marketing&utm_term=visit%20the%20full%20post).

---

I have solved it with this one-liner (adjust it to your models/fields)

`$this->assertEquals($store->settings, Store::find($store->id)->settings);`

Answer (score 5):

## Laravel 7+

Not sure how far back this solution works.

I found out the solution.  Ignore some of the data label, Everything is accessible, i was just play around with my tests to figure it out.

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function canUpdate()
{
    $authUser = UserFactory::createDefault();
    $this->actingAs($authUser);

    $generator = GeneratorFactory::createDefault();

    $request = [
        'json_field_one' => [
            'array-data',
            ['more-data' => 'cool'],
            'data' => 'some-data',
            'collection' => [
                ['key' => 'value'],
                'data' => 'some-more-data'
            ],
        ],
        'json_field_two' => [],
    ];

    $response = $this->putJson("/api/generators/{$generator->id}", $request);
    $response->assertOk();

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('generators', [
        'id' => $generator->id,
        'generator_set_id' => $generator->generatorSet->id,

        // Testing for json requires arrows for accessing the data
        // For Collection data, you should use numbers to access the indexes
        // Note:  Mysql dose not guarantee array order if i recall. Dont quote me on that but i'm pretty sure i read that somewhere.  But for testing this works
        'json_field_one->0' => 'array-data',
        'json_field_one->1->more-data' => 'cool',

        // to access properties just arrow over to the property name
        'json_field_one->data' => 'some-data',
        'json_field_one->collection->data' => 'some-more-data',

        // Nested Collection
        'json_field_one->collection->0->key' => 'value',

        // Janky way to test for empty array
        // Not really testing for empty
        // only that the 0 index is not set
        'json_field_two->0' => null,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hm...if this works, this is awesome! But, please, clean up your answer. It's really worth being posted, just...could you make it more convenient for other devs?))

Comment: Damn, I need this `'prompters->collectionA->0->not-working' => 'cant-access',` to work.

Comment: It works, ill update the words so its not confusing, that was me playing around and when it worked i just pasted the results.  My bad.  @ChristhoferNatalius

Comment: @ShawnPivonka doesn't work for me, that's why I commented. idk why. I switched to assertEquals instead.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius i think the issue is I'm using Laravel 7.  Im guessing for 5.6 this might not work.  What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @ShawnPivonka I'm on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note: The below solution is tested on Laravel Version: 9.x and Postgres version: 12.x**
> **and the solution might not work on lower version of laravel**

There would be two condition to assert json column into database.

##### 1. Object

Consider Object is in json column in database as shown below:

```json
 "properties" => "{"attributes":{"id":1}}"
```

It can assert as

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas("table_name",[
    "properties->attributes->id"=>1
]);
```

##### 2. Array

Consider array is in json column as shown below:

```json
 "properties" => "[{"id":1},{"id":2}]"
```

It can assert as

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas("table_name",[
    "properties->0->id"=>1,
    "properties->1->id"=>2,
]);
```

Comment: Just FYI, `"properties->0->id"=>1,` doesn't work in Laravel 9. Object — does.

Comment: Interesting ! which database you are using?

Comment: Right now it's MySQL 8. Checked and confirm, that nope. Still has to be old-fashioned. 

Object syntax works, soo...it's something ‍♂️

But funny, that the issue goes for 4 years.

Comment: The above solution is tested on **Postgres** version: 12.x, as mentioned above, not sure about  MySQL.

Comment: not too late to make a switch 

Answer (score 1):

if you want to assert array in your databases, you can use something like this:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas(ModelSettings::class, ['settings->array[0]' => 'value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `json_encode` on the value worked for me:

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
    'name' => 'Gaurav',
    'attributes' => json_encode([
        'gender' => 'Male',
        'nationality' => 'Indian',
    ]),
]);
```